# How to structure a child component that performs its own validation without reinventing the wheel?

Tags: forms, angular, validation, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I feel like this is a very common thing to need to do, but I can't find any guidance in the Angular docs or elsewhere as to what is best practice.

Situation: I have a parent component that uses Reactive Forms to perform validation for its data. One of the child components is a component with 10+ additional inputs, checkboxes, and radio buttons. This child component is used in another section of the application as well (its other parent uses `ngModel` for data binding with this child component), so I would like to have the child be able to perform its own validation checks and display error messages accordingly while the parent's data for the child component gets updated via `ngModel` or `formControlName` (however the parent component wishes). All of this works once `ControlValueAccessor` is implemented in the child component.

Where I'm stuck: Since the child component is performing it's own validation, when the parent is using Reactive Forms, the validity of the child should be reflected in the parent form.

Here are the two options I see:

1. (Child FormGroup) The child component uses Reactive Forms itself, using `formControlName` for data binding and `FormBuilder` and `Validators` for clean form control instantiation and validation logic.
2. (Manual Validation) The child component uses `ngModel` to bind it's control values to the data and implements the `Validator` interface. Each field would need it's own 'validation' method that would get called via `(ngModelChange)` to run validity logic, display error messages if necessary, etc. This feels like I'm re-doing a lot of the logic that is supposedly abstracted away by using Reactive Forms and just feels messy, as we need a validation method for each field, a component variable to track each field's validity, doesn't seem to offer a clean way to add additional controls later if needed, and just seems error-prone. I've seen some suggestions that mention I can pass the parent form into the child component via `@Input()`, but this would force the parent of the child to implement Reactive Forms, which is a restriction that I don't feel is necessary since components shouldn't care about what their parent is - their job is to display data and handle changes to the data.

I would like to go with option 1, but I'm having issues with the parent component 'seeing' the validity of the child's data. I made a simple [StackBlitz example to show what I'm taking about](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ty3xtz).

StackBlitz notes: Form1Component is using above-mentioned option 1, Form2Component is using above-mentioned option 2. You can see the issue I'm having in the formGroup section of Form1Component - causing the child form to be invalid (via clearing the `<input>` text or selecting the empty `<select>` option) does not cause the parent form to be invalid as well. Conversely, invalidating the child component in the Form2Component section causes the parent form to be invalid, but this doesn't feel like it's the 'right' way to do this due to the above-mentioned reasons. Any ideas?

Comment: The forms in `Form1Component` works as they should?

Comment: In the **formGroup** section of Form1Component: if the child component is invalid, the parent is still considered valid and will allow for submission. This is the problem.